# Ways to learn mathematics

Tags: self-learning, education, learning

I will be graduating with my bachelor's degree in mechanical engineering, in a few months, but I want to pursue master's in mathematics after 2-3 years. To prepare, I am currently doing "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" by kreyszig but wanted to do some additional stuff alongside, after thinking, I boiled down my options to following two categories; either I can do some mathematics project involving various mathematical topics intermixing or I can work on some open-ended problem in mathematics giving me an in depth understanding of the field. In addition, my area of interest in mathematics is primarily probability & statistics and numerical analysis but I am open to other fields in mathematics having weak correlation to the above mentioned areas too. I need help in deciding which approach will be best for learning mathematics alongside helping me prepare for my master's in mathematics with some solid work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would also bring this question to the head of the Mathematics Department at your school and professors there in your specific areas of interest.  You may also want to check out academia.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should post it on academia.stackexchange too.